# What is the base chance of the Cryo Ammo power to freeze an enemy?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The Cryo Ammo power has a certain chance to freeze the enemies you shoot at, but the description of the power doesn't mention how high that chance actually is. The second rank of that power increases the chance to freeze an enemy by 30%, but 30% of what?

[image]

How high is the base chance to freeze an enemy?

Comment: Don't know the specifics, but it's based on the weapon it's used on, not just a base chance. I know snipers have the highest chance of freezing, and shotguns the second highest and etc.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely weighted by gun. Generally 1 second of sustained fire from any gun (even if it's only one shot) should freeze an enemy. Be interesting to know the exact numbers, but I'm not sure they're out there publicly

Comment: @MrSmooth Really? Where's that stated?

Comment: @FAE it's not stated (best I know of) but you can test it easy with a rapid fire gun and a slow fire heavy pistol. Almost every shot with the pistol freezes/chills but it takes a few rounds of an SMG to freeze often.

Comment: @FAE I don't think it's stated anywhere, I just know that that's how it worked in Mass Effect 2 (in fact snipers had a 100% chance in ME2, with shotguns almost 100% due to the amount of bullets that could hit), and I'm assuming that it continues in the same fashion, otherwise you're at a sever disadvantage using cryo-ammo on a slow firing weapon compared to say an SMG.

Comment: The base chance appears to be 100%, but obviously there's penalty multipliers involved somewhere that make the *effective* chance lower. I'm not sure what factors into that calculation at the moment, unfortunately.

Comment: Interesting. I run Squad Cryo, but Incendiary on myself, so I didn't actively notice the difference in effectiveness on various weapons. I thought it was just a mistake in my perception.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the fire rate of weapon, a sniper or shotgun will often freeze in a single hit, while automatic weapons often requite several rounds of fire.